# Android : can't find a sync adapter

Tags: android, provider, accountmanager

Why Android don't find my sync adapter when i call :

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, "com.stevegrosbois.budget.provider", true);
```

I have searched for hours :

In the Log :

```
DEBUG/SyncManager(59): can't find a sync adapter for SyncAdapterType Key {name=com.stevegrosbois.budget.provider, type=com.stevegrosbois.budget.user}, removing settings for it
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".sync.SyncService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

syncadapter.xml :

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    contentAuthority="com.stevegrosbois.budget.provider"
    accountType="com.stevegrosbois.budget.user"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:userVisible="true"
/>
```

I have tried everything

And now i'm crying :'(

Comment: How do you define the provider in the manifest? Do use a provider at all? You have to define one also you might not use it.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND !!!!

android:contentAuthority instead of contentAuthority in my syncadapter.xml file

also android:accountType instead of accountType